# How to autoscroll on split pages e.g. google maps?

Tags: python, selenium, web-scraping, autoscroll

Working on scraping google maps (reviews) with python/selenium.

The following doesn't scroll:

```
self.driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0,document.body.scrollHeight);")
```

Assuming this is due to the split page as similar code has worked on other sites.

I'm sure someone has dealt with this issue before. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

This is something you wanna give a try to see how you can scroll a split window/screen. The html structures keep changing so you should comply with the logic I tried below. I have shown this using hardcoded delay which you can replace with `Explicit Wait` as per your requirement.

Run it as it is:

```
import time
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys

link = 'https://www.google.com.bd/maps/search/Florida+coffee/@27.604325,-80.9640709,9z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=en'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
# time.sleep(3) #If the code breaks, activate this line. You should see the scroll being executed
elem = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("[data-section-id^='or:']")
for _ in range(2):
    elem.send_keys(Keys.END)
    time.sleep(2)

driver.quit()
```

To get the names:

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.support import ui
import pandas as pd

link = 'https://www.google.com.bd/maps/search/Florida+coffee/@27.604325,-80.9640709,9z/data=!3m1!4b1?hl=en'

driver = webdriver.Chrome()
driver.get(link)
wait = ui.WebDriverWait(driver, 10)
elem = [item.text for item in wait.until(lambda driver: driver.find_elements_by_css_selector("h3.section-result-title"))]
df = pd.DataFrame(elem)
print(df)
driver.quit()
```

Comment: Hey @SIM, apologies old thread. is the above the total code to scrape reviews? is there any way to push this into a pandas dataframe?

Comment: You are my hero! Thanks buddy